# ¿Cómo contar el número de filas de todas las tablas de un esquema?

Tags: sql, oracle

Necesito realizar un *export* de los registros de algunas tablas de un mismo esquema en [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle), pero por limitaciones en la máquina desde la cual voy a realizar este proceso necesito conocer el número de filas de las tablas de dicho esquema para decidir si lo hago así o utilizo otra alternativa para copiar los registros entre un ambiente y otro.

¿Cómo puedo determinar de forma rápida y efectiva el número de registros de todas las tablas en el esquema?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

La forma más sencilla de lograrlo, es decir sin procedimientos ni cosas complejas, es ejecutar la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT owner, table_name, num_rows, sample_size, last_analyzed 
FROM all_tables
WHERE owner = 'nombre_de_tu_esquema';
```

La columna `num_rows` contiene el número de filas o registros de cada una de las tablas.

---

Actualización:

Como destaca @jpertejo:

> Hay que tener en cuenta que la columna `NUM_ROWS` de la vista
>   `ALL_TABLES` obtiene la información de las estadísticas de la tabla.
>   Si las estadísticas no están actualizadas puede ser que el número de
>   filas que devuelve el `NUM_ROWS` no se corresponda con el real. Para
>   saber con exactitud en número real de filas habría que hacer un
>   `COUNT(*)`. La consulta del `NUM_ROWS` es más rápida que el
>   `COUNT(*)`, pero puede no dar datos correctos en algunos casos.

De aquí que en la consulta se incluya la columna `last_analyzed` cuyo fin es informar la fecha en la que se hizo el más reciente análisis estadístico para cada tabla.

Comment: Lo más correcto no es responderte a ti mismo, sino editar tu pregunta con la respuesta. Saludos

Comment: @eugenio Según el fundador de StackOverflow, [no solo está bien hacerlo así sino que se alienta a hacerlo](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). De hecho, si hubieras leído la FAQ de este sitio, habrías comprobado que [esto aplica en este sitio también](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @eugenio nada que ver, es correcto lo que dice francisco, más bien sería bueno que comentaras si fuiste tú quien le dio negativo a su respuesta, por eso que comentas o porque la consulta no cumple su cometido?, no tengo manera de testearlo.

Comment: Edita la respuesta sino no puedo editar mi voto. Pero me sigue pareciendo absurdo que tu mismo te respondas, sobretodo ahora que está en beta pública. Pues eso, edita la respuesta y te quito el negativo.

Comment: @eugenio, no hay ningún absurdo, pero mejor hablar respecto a eso en el [meta]

Comment: No veo problema, si tu mismo te lo solucionas pues que bueno, perfectamente te quedas callado y otro se queda con la duda, así que esta perfecto.

Comment: Hay que tener en cuenta que la columna NUM_ROWS de la vista ALL_TABLES obtiene la información de las estadísticas de la tabla. Si las estadísticas no están actualizadas puede ser que el número de filas que devuelve el NUM_ROWS no se corresponda con el real.  Para saber con exactitud en número real de filas habría que hacer un COUNT(\*). La consulta del NUM_ROWS es más rápida que el COUNT(\*), pero puede no dar datos correctos en algunos casos.

Comment: Correcto, @jpertejo, de ahí la importancia de la columna `last_analyzed` que indica la fecha en la que se hizo el más reciente análisis estadístico para esa tabla.

Comment: OK @FranciscoAlvarado, pero creo que sería importante que quedara claro en la respuesta para evitar confusiones.

Comment: @jpertejo incluyo tu comentario en mi respuesta (sin cambios, tal y como lo escribiste) para el caso en el que quede oculto cuando la vista de comentarios esté plegada. Gracias por tu valioso aporte.